# How do you ask something which is not exactly "half a glass"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, terminology

I know to ask,

> Please, fill half a glass of water/tea.

Well, the context for the above sentence is understandable. But, what if I need to ask the same, where

Cases:

1. The tea/water is more than half but not full.
2. It is less than half but neither empty nor very little.

Do we have any words/sentences to express for these two cases?
I guess we can't say:

> Please fill 25% or 37% of tea OR 75% of water

Comment: Not sure how filling 37% percent of water in a glass is possible...

Comment: Filling *half* or a *third/fourth/three-fourths* of a glass with water is more standard.

Comment: 'Give me a drop' would be colloquially understood in UK English as just a small amount of liquid in a glass - if it was water or a soft drink. Unfortunately 'Give me a drop' when applied to alcoholic drinks might mean the same, or might mean 'fill my glass'!

Comment: "Give me some water." Or you could say "Just fill it a quarter of the way up" or something. You could say "Give me 375 ml" or "fill it 67% full", that's certainly grammatical. People might wonder why you were being so precise (unless you were making a recipe or were a chemist or something), but that's outside the scope of English Language and Usage.

Comment: Please give me a glass that is just under/over half full. Or for the title question, please give me a glass that is about half full.

Comment: @Justin - weigh the glass full and empty, do some simple arithmetic, pour until the desired weight is reached.

Comment: Dude. How do you handle this problem in your own language? English, as another language, is not going to be that different. Please don't tell me you go around to servers and say, "Fill my glass to 29.20% of its volume".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Ah, of course. But people don't have time to do stuff like this... (Do they?)

Comment: "Would you like another cup of tea?" "Yes, please, but don't fill it right to the top," or "Can you fill it about a quarter full?" Sometimes the person pouring says "Say when" (I should stop pouring).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use any word for a small amount, and make it relative to the half-full mark. For example, you could ask for the glass to be filled

1. **just shy of** half full
2. **a tad more than** half full

Comment: Is the word full needed at all? Can I just say "a tad more than half"?

Comment: Certainly, I think that by Grice's principles most people would presume *half full* if you only say *half*, but you could imagine a context where it would be ambiguous. “Glass A is half empty and glass B is a tad more”: is B a tad more than half full, or a tad less than full because it is a tad more empty?